# Why can't I install vpython from terminal?

Tags: python, pip, subprocess

I tried to install vpython from the terminal with the command 'pip install vpython', but it throws me this error. I have python 3.8.9 and windows 7, 32 bits. I also tried installing other libraries like numpy, and I did it successfully.

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pywinpty (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [57 lines of output]
      Running `maturin pep517 build-wheel -i c:\users\mateo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe --compatibility off`
         Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
         Compiling libc v0.2.121
         Compiling pyo3-build-config v0.16.2
         Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.36
      error: could not compile `proc-macro2` due to 2 previous errors
      warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
      error: build failed
      ðŸ’¥ maturin failed
        Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo

        Caused by: Cargo build finished with "exit code: 101": `cargo rustc --manifest-path Cargo.toml --message-format json --release --lib --`
      ðŸ\x8d¹ Building a mixed python/rust project
      ðŸ”— Found pyo3 bindings
      ðŸ\x90\x8d Found CPython 3.8 at c:\users\mateo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found
     
     
      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found
     
     
      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option
     
     
      error: aborting due to previous error
     
     
      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found
     
     
      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found
     
     
      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option
     
     
      error: aborting due to previous error
     
     
      error: linker `link.exe` not found
        |
        = note: program not found
     
     
      note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found
     
     
      note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017 or VS 2019 was installed with the Visual C++ option
     
     
      error: aborting due to previous error
     
     
      Error: command ['maturin', 'pep517', 'build-wheel', '-i', 'c:\\users\\mateo\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '--compatibility', 'off'] returned non-zero exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywinpty
Failed to build pywinpty
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pywinpty, which is required to
install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to put PATH and I also installed cargo, because it threw me another error. I expect to install vpython from the terminal with pip successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using python 32bit, you should use 64bit one instead. Uninstall your 32bit version and install 64bit. I believe that your problem would be solved.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I have windows 7 32bits, should I install windows 10 64bits?

Comment: Yes friend, it would probably fix this error